# Where is the details of extension of Safari 8 is stored in Yosemite(Mac OS 10.10)

Tags: safari, safari-extension, osx-yosemite

I want to install the safari extension in Safari v8 in Yosemite(Mac OS 10.10) by programmatically.
As in safari v5,v6,v7 for extension details, safari maintain Extensions.plist which is stored at ~/Library/Safari/Extensions/Extensions.plist. But in safari v8 there is no information in Extensions.plist for installed extensions like extension is enabled or not.

So is there anyone who knows how safari v8 stores its Extensions information and where?

Comment: Sam, Have you got a solution for this, even i am trying to find where the extension enable state is stored for Safari 8 on Mac OS 10.10

Comment: Swetha, I am still looking into it. If you get the answer then please let me know.

Comment: I do see the extension information in Extensions.plist file, but all my extensions are turned off when I start Safari, even though the extensions.plist file says enabled. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Since safari 6.2, 7.1 and 8.0 it is stored as binary plist in `~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` as a generic password with title "Safari Extensions List"

You can access it by the `Keychain.app` or `/usr/bin/security` or [security framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/SecurityObjectiveC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000996)

Comment: kimo, I have tried to read the login.keychain information but I did not get any information related to Safari Extension List.
Have you read this information?

Comment: yes. For example in Terminal using `secutiry find-generic-password -ga Safari`

Comment: On 10.8.5 I can't get it to show me the “password”: `Keychain.app` reverts the “show password” checkbox to unset after accepting my password, and `security` exits with return value 51 if I pass the `-g` or `-w` switch. But I trust that nevertheless this is where the setting is kept, which was what kept me looking for quite a while now. Thanks a lot for this information!!!