# Where is the safari (v7.1) extension enable state is stored in Mavericks 10.9.5

Tags: macos, safari, osx-mavericks, safari-extension

In OS X before Mavericks 10.9.5, If Safari extension is enabled/disabled then enable state is stored into ~/Library/Safari/Extensions/Extensions.plist. But in 10.9.5 it is not store into the Extensions.plist file. Extensions.plist file does not exist at ~/Library/Safari/Extensions location. Any ideas about where is the extension enable state is stored for Safari 7.1 on Mac OS 10.9.5?

Comment: Answer is in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26052864/1918865

Answer (score 0):

You can find the extension state for Safari in ~/Library/Preferences/ stored in com.apple.Safari.plist with the key name ExtensionsEnabled.

Comment: Hi runnick, If you toggle the on/off button from the Safari->Prefrences->Extensions then ExtensionsEnabled states is getting modified. I am aware of this. If I disabled the particular extension then where is it going to store?